# Storing Sys.time() in a data frame

Tags: r, for-loop

I am currently trying to store the time of every step of a loop that pulls stock quotes through the package "tseries". Unfortunately, when trying to store `Sys.time()` in my data frame it doesn't store the time but a bunch of numbers.
First, I thought this might be an issue of `class()` and therefore attempted to use `as.POSIXct()` which resulted in the following error:
"Error in as.POSIXct.numeric(test[, 2]): 'origin' must be specified"

This code reproduces my problem:

```
Loop <- c(rep(NA,10))
Time <- c(rep(NA,10))
test <- cbind(Loop,Time)

for(i in 1:length(test[,1])){
  test[i,1] <- i
  test[i,2] <- Sys.time()
}

as.POSIXct(test[,2])
```

I would be grateful for any tips that allow me to solve this issue.

Comment: From: https://bookdown.org/rdpeng/rprogdatascience/dates-and-times.html

"while times are stored internally as the number of seconds since 1970-01-01."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specify an origin time?

```
as.POSIXct(test[,2], origin = "1970-01-01", tz = "UTC")
```